# Netbeans doesn't open new projects

Tags: java, netbeans-8

I'm running a windows 10 OS, with NetBeans version 8.2, and JDK 8 latest update version. The problem is that every time I try to open a new project or file in Netbeans, a blank screen appears, and after waiting nothing happens, I have repeated this process multiple times to no avail, I have even deleted and reinstalled both the JDK and Netbeans, but nothing changed. There are some answers on Stack Overflow already, but none of them seem to help my current problem.

[image]

Comment: in your home folder `C:\users\<yourusername>` there is a folder with name that starts with `.netbeans`. Close Netbeans if it is open. Then delete this folder. After that launch Netbeans again. It should help.

Comment: I tried that already, it didn't work out, it still has the same problem, I copied the file just in case it causes problems, and the Netbeans application launcher gave me an error, something like .... file not found

Comment: please report this issue here: https://netbeans.org/community/issues.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry about that. My computer's hard drive had crashed and had to send it to get it replaced and when it came it was a complete blank slate. But turns it out had JDK 9.0.4 running on it and with that JDK it somehow caused problems. I checked all the system files, deleted that version, reinstalled JDK 8 and it reinstalled Netbeans with reference to Java version 8, and it started running.